# Making getBounds() work in External Function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get `getBounds()` to work.

When I have this code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', createMarkerButton(marker,map));

function createMarkerButton(marker,map) {

    alert(map.getBounds());
    ......

  }
```

I get an error saying that `getBounds()` is undefined.

However if I do this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function(){

     alert(map.getBounds());

});
```

It works perfectly fine. However, I need get bounds to work in the `createMarkerButton` function. How might I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code is passing the return value of `createMarkerButton` instead of the function itself.

Try this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function(){createMarkerButton(marker,map)});
```